# How do i put an index on an array element using Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How do I index an array element in mongoose, this is what i am trying in my schema, but its not working

```
locations : [{ 
    loc: { type: [Number], index: '2d'}
 }]
```

Comment: That looks ok.  What's not working about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Number] means array of numbers....
If want an array with out define the type you can use Mixed type like this :

```
loc: { type: [], index: '2d'}
```

Or

```
loc: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, index: '2d'}
```

And by the way this is a [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-SchemaType) for mongoose schema types